# Highcharts: How to move the column bar to the left most side when there is only one point in drilldown

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, drilldown, column-chart

I have a column chart with drilldown. Here is my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/fkk4b/)**

The drilldown has only one point to show up. Now what I want to do is:

**In drilldown I want to move the column bar to the left most side instead of its current middle position. So that I can add some HTML text elements using Highcharts renderer API.**

I have reduced the width of the column using `pointWidth` option and now a single point looks bad stuck in the middle.

I have searched through all the options of the Highcharts API but I did not get any such option with which I can achieve this. Do anybody has any idea ? Here is my code:

```
$(function () {   

    var renderer;    
    var groups = {};

    (function (H) {
        //DATALABELS
        H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function (proceed) {
var css = this.chart.options.drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle;
            proceed.call(this);

            css.textDecoration = 'none';
            css.fontWeight = 'normal';
            css.cursor = 'default';
            css.color = 'blue';


            H.each(this.points, function (point) {

                if (point.drilldown && point.dataLabel) {
                    point.dataLabel
                        .css(css)
                        .on('click', function () {
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        //For X-axis labels
        H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'init', function (proceed, series, options, x) {
            var point = proceed.call(this, series, options, x),
                chart = series.chart,
                tick = series.xAxis && series.xAxis.ticks[x],
                tickLabel = tick && tick.label;
            //console.log("series");
            //console.log(series);
            console.log("Point = ");
            console.log(point.name);

            if (point.drilldown) {

                if (tickLabel) {
                    if (!tickLabel._basicStyle) {
                        tickLabel._basicStyle = tickLabel.element.getAttribute('style');
                    }
                    tickLabel.addClass('highcharts-drilldown-axis-label')          .css({
                        'text-decoration': 'none',
                        'font-weight': 'normal',
                        'cursor': 'auto',
                        'color':'brown'
                        }).on('click', function () {
                            if (point.doDrilldown) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });//remove this "on" block to make axis labels clickable
                }
            } 
            else if (tickLabel && tickLabel._basicStyle) 
            {
            }

            return point;
        });
    })(Highcharts);

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            //drillUpText: '<< Terug naar {series.name}'
        }
    });


    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        colors:['red','orange','orange','green'],
            tooltip:false,
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                    drillup: function (e) {
                        //alert('drill Up');
                        show_hide_drilldown_texts('','');
                        /*console.log(this);
                        console.log(this.options.series[0].name);
                        console.log(this.options.series[0].data[0].name);*/
                    }
                }  
            },

            title: {
                text: 'This is customized column chart'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                /*categories: [
                    'Smallest Priority',
                    'Performance inprovement Priority',
                    'Performance inprovement Priority',
                    'Biggest Priority'
                ],*/
               lineWidth: 2,
               minorTickLength: 0,
               tickLength: 0,
            },

            yAxis: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Uplift Opportunity'
                },
                labels:{
                    enabled:false
                }
            },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    /*point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {alert(this.name);
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                if (drilldown) { // drill down

                                } else { // restore

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },*/
                    //pointPadding: 0.2,
                    //borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        align: 'center',
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        inside: true//,
                        //overflow:"justify"
                    },
                    pointPadding: 0.1,
                    groupPadding: 0
                }
            }, 

        series: [{
            name: 'Main',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Smallest Priority',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'priority1',
                dataLabels: {
                    format: 'This is column 1'
                },
                events:{
                    click: function() {//console.log(this);
                        //alert("hey");
                        show_hide_drilldown_texts('group1','show');
                    }
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Performance improvement Priority',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'priority2',
                dataLabels: {
                    format: 'This is column 2'
                },
                events:{
                    click: function() {
                        show_hide_drilldown_texts('group2','show');
                    }
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Performance improvement Priority',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'priority3',
                dataLabels: {
                    format: 'This is column 3'
                },
                events:{
                    click: function() {
                        show_hide_drilldown_texts('group3','show');
                    }
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Biggest Priority',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'priority4',
                dataLabels: {
                    format: 'This is column 4'//,
                    //overflow:"justify"
                },
                events:{
                    click: function() {
                        show_hide_drilldown_texts('group4','show');
                    }
                }
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [
                {
                    id: 'priority1',
                    color:"Gray",
                    pointWidth:80,
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: 'This is drilldown of column 1'
                    },
                    data: [
                        ['Smallest Priority', 2]
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    id: 'priority2',
                    color:"Gray",
                    pointWidth:80,
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: 'This is drilldown of column 2'
                    },
                    data: [
                        ['Performance improvement Priority', 3]
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    id: 'priority3',
                    color:"Gray",
                    pointWidth:80,
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: 'This is drilldwon of column 3'
                    },
                    data: [
                        ['Performance improvement Priority', 4]
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    id: 'priority4',
                    color:"Gray",
                    pointWidth:80,
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: 'This is drilldwon of column 4'
                    },
                    data: [
                        ['Biggest Priority', 5]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }, function(chart) { // on complete
            renderer = chart.renderer;
            group = renderer.g().add();
            group2 = renderer.g().add();

            groups.group1 = renderer.g().add();
            groups.group2 = renderer.g().add();
            groups.group3 = renderer.g().add();
            groups.group4 = renderer.g().add();

            var drilldown_text_1 = renderer.text('This is <span style="color: red">drilldown text 1</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 150, 80)
            .css({
                color: '#4572A7',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }).add(groups.group1);

            var drilldown_text_2 = renderer.text('This is <span style="color: blue">drilldown text 2</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 150, 80)
            .css({
                color: '#4572A7',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }).add(groups.group2);

            var drilldown_text_3 = renderer.text('This is <span style="color: blue">drilldown text 3</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 150, 80)
            .css({
                color: '#4572A7',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }).add(groups.group3);

            var drilldown_text_4 = renderer.text('This is <span style="color: blue">drilldown text 4</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 150, 80)
            .css({
                color: '#4572A7',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }).add(groups.group4);

        });
/*
console.log("renderer = ");  
console.log(renderer); 
*/
//console.log("groups = ");  
//console.log(groups); 

//groups.group2.hide();    

show_hide_drilldown_texts('','');
function show_hide_drilldown_texts(text_group_name, action)
{
    //alert('show_hide_drilldown_texts    text_group_name = '+text_group_name+ ' action = '+action);

    $.each( groups, function( key, elem ) {
        //console.log('key');console.log(key);
        //console.log('elem');console.log(elem);
        if(text_group_name != '' && action == "show" && key == text_group_name)
        {
            elem.show();
        }
        else
        {    
            elem.hide();
        }
    });
}    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `minRange` and `min` for xAxis. Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fkk4b/3/

```
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            /*categories: [
                'Smallest Priority',
                'Performance inprovement Priority',
                'Performance inprovement Priority',
                'Biggest Priority'
            ],*/
            min: 0,
            minRange: 3,
           lineWidth: 2,
           minorTickLength: 0,
           tickLength: 0,
        },
```

Not universal solution, but works for the same number of categories in one chart.

**EDIT:**

To remove extra labels, use formatter:

```
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    if(this.axis.series[0].levelNumber == 1 && !this.isFirst )  {
                        return ''; 
                    } else {
                         return this.value;   
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well it good ! but is there any way to hide the other useless labels on x-axis in drilldown ?

Comment: Well, you can use `xAxis.labels.formatter`, to check level of drilldown, and display only one label. Other solution will be to use `pointPlacement`, but unfortuntely, doesn't work for drilldown points.

Comment: Can you please update your fiddle while using `xAxis.labels.formatter` ??

Comment: Wow ! Thanks man ! Please update you answer appropriately so that I can accept it. !